# Best way to update watchOS complications

Tags: ios, swift, watch

I have a watchOS complication and companion iOS app. I want to update the complication every 10 minutes. I make ~20 API calls ( URLSession.shared.dataTask) each time I refresh the data.

Is it better (more reliable, less resource intensive) to run schedule iOS app background refresh and make the API calls there, then update complication when done,

Or make API calls on watchOS app and update complication when done?

I'm asking because as I understand, Apple doesn't like frequent refreshes and I feel like consuming iPhone resources is preferable to Watch resources.

Comment: I would suggest you to create an communication between app and apple watch by using an session manager approach. 
Also implement your webservices in the app not in watch. It's will make your app faster and more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Resources wise, I would suggest to run the schedule in iOS app background with the API calls and then update complication when done. This approach is more reliable and resources intensive.